# Something went wrong while installing Helm Tiller Can’t start installation process

Tags: kubernetes

I have installed AKS(azure kubernetes service) but once I try to integrate it with Gitlab next message appear ***Something went wrong while installing Helm Tiller Can’t start installation process***

I am not sure how to access to k8s cluster to make a deeper research due azure just create a couple of VM for minions but not a VM for the k8s cluster.

Hope someone can have an idea